# How can i sort array with objects which have property with another array of objects but not with ES6

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of array with objects. In each object except properties i have another array with objects called "secondary_fields". I need to access the last element in the secondary_fields array (secondary_fields[3]) where i have value of when it is created and after that to sort all of the objects

by the date time based on the value inside for example "2020-01-13 17:42:51";

But not with ES6 because i am using old platform where the ES6 version of Java Script is not supported

```
let arr = 
  [
    {
        "external": false,
        "link": "--",
        "direct": false,
        "display_field": "new best article",
        "id": "kb_knowledge:33",
        "secondary_fields": [
          {
            "display_value": "Test Admin",
            "name": "author",
            "label": "Author",
            "type": "reference",
            "value": "xx"
          },
          {
            "display_value": "25",
            "name": "sys_view_count",
            "label": "View count",
            "type": "integer",
            "value": "25"
          },
          {
            "display_value": "2020-01-13 09:44:54",
            "name": "sys_updated_on",
            "label": "Updated",
            "type": "glide_date_time",
            "value": "2020-01-13 17:44:54"
          },
          {
            "display_value": "2020-01-13 09:42:51",
            "name": "sys_created_on",
            "label": "Created",
            "type": "glide_date_time",
            "value": "2020-01-13 17:42:51"
          }
        ],
      },


      {
        "external": false,
        "link": "--",
        "direct": false,
        "display_field": "How to connect the iPod to Wi-Fi",
        "id": "kb_knowledge:11",
        "secondary_fields": [
          {
            "display_value": "John",
            "name": "author",
            "label": "Author",
            "type": "reference",
            "value": "xxnnx"
          },
          {
            "display_value": "16",
            "name": "sys_view_count",
            "label": "View count",
            "type": "integer",
            "value": "16"
          },
          {
            "display_value": "2019-12-18 08:18:08",
            "name": "sys_updated_on",
            "label": "Updated",
            "type": "glide_date_time",
            "value": "2019-12-18 16:18:08"
          },
          {
            "display_value": "2019-10-21 12:27:22",
            "name": "sys_created_on",
            "label": "Created",
            "type": "glide_date_time",
            "value": "2019-10-21 19:27:22"
          }
        ],
      }
  ]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47545956/2891356

Comment: I added example without es6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = 
  [
    {
        "external": false,
        "link": "--",
        "direct": false,
        "display_field": "new best article",
        "id": "kb_knowledge:33",
        "secondary_fields": [
          {
            "display_value": "Test Admin",
            "name": "author",
            "label": "Author",
            "type": "reference",
            "value": "xx"
          },
          {
            "display_value": "25",
            "name": "sys_view_count",
            "label": "View count",
            "type": "integer",
            "value": "25"
          },
          {
            "display_value": "2020-01-13 09:44:54",
            "name": "sys_updated_on",
            "label": "Updated",
            "type": "glide_date_time",
            "value": "2020-01-13 17:44:54"
          },
          {
            "display_value": "2020-01-13 09:42:51",
            "name": "sys_created_on",
            "label": "Created",
            "type": "glide_date_time",
            "value": "2020-01-13 17:42:51"
          }
        ],
      },


      {
        "external": false,
        "link": "--",
        "direct": false,
        "display_field": "How to connect the iPod to Wi-Fi",
        "id": "kb_knowledge:11",
        "secondary_fields": [
          {
            "display_value": "John",
            "name": "author",
            "label": "Author",
            "type": "reference",
            "value": "xxnnx"
          },
          {
            "display_value": "16",
            "name": "sys_view_count",
            "label": "View count",
            "type": "integer",
            "value": "16"
          },
          {
            "display_value": "2019-12-18 08:18:08",
            "name": "sys_updated_on",
            "label": "Updated",
            "type": "glide_date_time",
            "value": "2019-12-18 16:18:08"
          },
          {
            "display_value": "2019-10-21 12:27:22",
            "name": "sys_created_on",
            "label": "Created",
            "type": "glide_date_time",
            "value": "2019-10-21 19:27:22"
          }
        ],
      }
  ]
  
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return new Date(b.secondary_fields[3].display_value) - new Date(a.secondary_fields[3].display_value)
}) 
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: You should sort by `display_value` property.

Comment: @slawek763  i am using old platform where the ES6 version of Java Script is not supported

Comment: I updated display_val and removed es6

Comment: You probably don't want to use the "let" keyword either.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the array method's `sort` method and sort on `display_value`.

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.secondary_fields[3].display_value) - new Date(b.secondary_fields[3].display_value)
})
```

#### Edit

Or I guess in your case,

```
return new Date(b.secondary_fields[3].display_value) - new Date(a.secondary_fields[3].display_value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.But  i am using old platform where the ES6 version of Java Script is not supported

Comment: `array.sort` is not ES6

Comment: You can also look at something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28853817/2891356).

Comment: @MikeK but arrow function is :D

Comment: Just get rid of the arrow and put the word `function` lol

Comment: I've updated my answer.